# EditorConfig optional suffix for Classes

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0, editorconfig

I want my classes to be in PascalCase, but I also have some DTOs that end with "DTO". (For example "MyClassDTO". Is it possible to add an optional Suffix for DTOs in the EditorConfig? I don't want to get warnings for my DTO classes but I also want to keep the rest of the classes in PascalCasing so DTOs are an exception.

Comment: `Is it possible to add an optional Suffix for DTOs?`I think it is ok.DTOs are classes,you can name them the way you want.

Comment: I know but i want to remove the warnings. The only solution i found was to rename all my DTOs. For example: MyDTO -> MyDto